# Is file upload with wxWidgets wxWebRequest supported?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I trying to send a curl command with wxWebRequest library.
Working Curl request looks like following:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:3000/page/auth/uploadFile?serialNumber=S123"
-H "accept: */*"
-H "language: en"
-H "Authorization: Bearer abcdefghijklmnopqrst"
-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"
-F "uploadFile=@./localUploadFile.txt;type=text/plain"
```

Only useful method I can find is `webRequest::SetData` but I cant find out how to utilize that to send `curl -F (form-data)`

```
void Upload::UploadFile(wxString resultFile, wxString token) {
    wxWebRequest request = tokenReq.GetDefault().CreateRequest(
        this,
        "http://localhost:3000/page/auth/uploadFile?serialNumber=S123"
);

request.SetMethod("POST");
request.SetHeader("accept", "*/*");
request.SetHeader("language", "en");
wxString tokenText = "Bearer " + token;
request.SetHeader("Authorization", tokenText);
request.SetHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8");

std::unique_ptr<wxInputStream> is(new wxFileInputStream(resultFile));
request.SetData(is.release(), "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");`
```

I understand that this wont work but this is the only thing I have come up with.

Is this even possible to do with `wxWebRequest`?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is currently no support for multipart/form-data in `wxWebRequest` itself. You can still use it for it, of course, but you'll need to implement encoding your data in the format, as [described by the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578) or use another library to do it.